# Are Sheet Music Searches On-topic?

Tags: discussion

I really don't know if this is on topic or not

> **Recreate Neil Diamond America**
>
> I have created arrangements by ear for four Simon & Garfunkel songs. I find it is difficult to arrange more songs by ear without having heard them frequently. I am wanting to add more sonhs in this category. (pop/rock hits from the 60s and 70s)
>
> I don't know if this is on topic or not, but surely someone else had created a sophisticated arrangement of this song before, so I thought I would ask. I don't know any other way to find one since the ones on the Google results seem to be little more than the main tune.
>
> I am not opposed to selecting other songs from this era.

If somebody can come up with real reasons one way or the other, we can have this decided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think programming should be on-topic, i.e. "What's an appropriate opener for a 40 minute long wind band concert consisting of the following pieces?"

However, the question you reference is easily answered by simple Google searches, as it concerns popular music, and you offer almost no constrains (though you do misplace the song in question in the wrong decade). For example:

- [neil diamond america piano arrangement - Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=neil+diamond+america+piano+arrangement&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)
- [piano sheet music pop rock 80s 90s - Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=piano+sheet+music+pop+rock+80s+90s&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

... would give you all the answers you're looking for as the question stands currently.