# Are questions like "Where can I find sheet music for ____" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

(I found [this similarly-titled question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235/are-sheet-music-searches-on-topic) which in reality seems quite unrelated; I apologize if this turns out to be a duplicate.)

I play piano, and I usually find new songs to learn by watching videos on YouTube and then finding sheet music for songs I particularly like (frequently from [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/wiki/)). However, there are occasions when I can't easily find sheet music for particular songs or certain arrangements thereof. Would it be appropriate/on-topic to ask for assistance in finding a particular piece of sheet music?

For example: "Where can I find sheet music for Saint-Saëns's piano solo arrangement of Sinfonia from Cantata No. 29 by Bach?" or "Where can I find sheet music for [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsJgxyHsAt8)?"

Comment: The other question *would* be a dupe, but it wasn't answered generally.  I don't like these questions, personally, but assuming you've done your homework they should be tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not, provided you indicate the sources you've already searched to save everyone's time including yours.